# is not a function, when function is right above?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this, devextreme

i often have the problem that i cant reach the Functions of my js classes inside the js class.
I mostly fix it with this. or a bind(this) but why does this not work? its the exact copy the way i do this in another class.

```
class Page {

     // constructor and props

     ShowNewJobPopup() {
        var popupNewJobElement = $("<div>").attr("id", "popupNewJob");
        console.log(data, element);
    }

    InitializeFilterElements(filterItems) {
        filterItems["Control"].Items.push({
            Template: function (itemElement) {
                itemElement.append("<div id=\"btnNeuerJob\" style=\"width: 100%; margin-top: 4px;\"></div>");
                $("#btnNeuerJob").dxButton({
                    type: "default",
                    text: "Neuer Job",
                    disabled: false,
                    onClick: function () {
                        this.ShowNewJobPopup(); // how is this not a function
                        
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            }
        });
        return filterItems;
    }
}
```

when im in the dev console. i can write Page.ShowNewJobPopup (Page is the script this is attached to)

Comment: `this.ShowNewJobPopup()` -> `console.log(this)` -> `this` = `#btnNeuerJob` (probably, not checked `dxButton`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` is actually not from the class Page.

We rewrite your Page class in the below way and you can see the `this` is referred to the `obj`.

```js
class Page {
    constructor() {}

    ShowNewJobPopup() {
        var popupNewJobElement = $("<div>").attr("id", "popupNewJob");
        console.log(data, element);
    }

    InitializeFilterElements(filterItems) {
        const obj = {
            Template: function (itemElement) {
                itemElement.append(
                    '<div id="btnNeuerJob" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 4px;"></div>'
                );
                $("#btnNeuerJob").dxButton({
                    type: "default",
                    text: "Neuer Job",
                    disabled: false,
                    onClick: function () {
                        this.ShowNewJobPopup(); 
                    }.bind(this), // this is referred to obj
                });
            },
        };

        filterItems["Control"].Items.push(obj);
        return filterItems;
    }
}
```

What you can do is create a variable `self` to store the `this` and use it to reference to the class Page later.

```js
class Page {
    constructor() {}

    ShowNewJobPopup() {
        var popupNewJobElement = $("<div>").attr("id", "popupNewJob");
        console.log(data, element);
    }

    InitializeFilterElements(filterItems) {
        const self = this; // this here is referred to the class Page

        const obj = {
            Template: function (itemElement) {
                itemElement.append(
                    '<div id="btnNeuerJob" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 4px;"></div>'
                );
                $("#btnNeuerJob").dxButton({
                    type: "default",
                    text: "Neuer Job",
                    disabled: false,
                    onClick: function () {
                        self.ShowNewJobPopup(); // self is referred to Page Class
                    },
                });
            },
        };

        filterItems["Control"].Items.push(obj);
        return filterItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good explaination of the problem here, this worked. (prob all others too) i think our philosophy of this in JS ( we come from c# ) is pretty dumbed, need to rethink our way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several functions with different `this` contexts nested within each other. It would be much simpler just to create a variable at the top of your class method rather than worrying about passing the right context to each function.

```js
InitializeFilterElements(filterItems) {
    const thisPage = this; // SET THE VARIABLE
    filterItems["Control"].Items.push({
        Template: function (itemElement) {
            itemElement.append("<div id=\"btnNeuerJob\" style=\"width: 100%; margin-top: 4px;\"></div>");
            $("#btnNeuerJob").dxButton({
                type: "default",
                text: "Neuer Job",
                disabled: false,
                onClick: function () {
                    thisPage.ShowNewJobPopup();                    
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return filterItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

```
InitializeFilterElements(filterItems) {
    const self = this; // self now holds the value of this reference
    filterItems["Control"].Items.push({
        Template: function (itemElement) {
            itemElement.append("<div id=\"btnNeuerJob\" style=\"width: 100%; margin-top: 4px;\"></div>");
            $("#btnNeuerJob").dxButton({
                type: "default",
                text: "Neuer Job",
                disabled: false,
                onClick: function () {
                    self.ShowNewJobPopup();                    
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return filterItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem of `this` in JavaScript. When the `Template` function is invoked, the reference of `this` changes to whatever the context of the object, in which the function is invoked.

Checkout the example for the error

A possible fix is

```
class Page {

 // constructor and props

 ShowNewJobPopup() {
    var popupNewJobElement = $("<div>").attr("id", "popupNewJob");
    console.log(data, element);
}

InitializeFilterElements(filterItems) {
    var that = this;
    filterItems["Control"].Items.push({
        Template: function (itemElement) {
            itemElement.append("<div id=\"btnNeuerJob\" style=\"width: 100%; margin-top: 4px;\"></div>");
            $("#btnNeuerJob").dxButton({
                type: "default",
                text: "Neuer Job",
                disabled: false,
                onClick: function () {
                    this.ShowNewJobPopup(); // how is this not a function
                    
                }.bind(that)
            });
        }
    });
    return filterItems;
}
```

}

```js
class A {

  test() {
    console.log("test")
  }

  test2() {
    let a = []
    a.push({
      template() {
        function abc() {
          console.log(this)
          this.test()
        }
        abc.bind(this)()
      }
    })
    return a
  }

}

let a = new A()

let arr = a.test2()

//this will work
arr[0].template.bind(a)()
console.log("===========")
arr[0].template()
```